# Cannot send message to certain channel using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently working on a discord bot, and I happened to run into this issue. I am relatively new to `discord.py`, and this is probably a newbie issue, but I would appreciate the help anyway :)

My current code:

```
@bot.listen()
async def on_message(message):
        messagecontent = message.content
        chan = message.channel
        if messagecontent.startswith("--"):
                pass
        else:
                embed=discord.Embed(title="Gathering Response...", color=0x00ffff)
                msg = bot.send_message(destination=chan,embed=embed)
```

When I run this and send a message, I receive no error message, or any feedback at all. It just does nothing. I would appreciate any help on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`send_message()` is a coroutine which means that you have to `await` it. It would look like:

```
msg = await bot.send_message(destination=chan,embed=embed)
```